# jquery selecting a Item

Tags: jquery, html

I have a form with a table.

```
<form >
    <div>   
    <table>
 <tr>        
       <td >  <input type="text" id="slno1" size="25" value="10" /> </td>     
       <td >  <input type="text" id="data" size="10" value="this is a test" /> </td>      
       <td >  <input type="radio"  value="" id="edit1" name="sample"  /> </td>    

  </tr>
   <tr>          
       <td >  <input type="text" id="slno2" size="25" value="10" /> </td>     
       <td >  <input type="text" id="data1" size="10" value="this is a test1" /> </td>    
       <td >  <input type="radio"  value="" id="edit1" name="sample"  /> </td>    
  </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="submit" id="mysu1" Value="submits" />  
    </div>
  </form>
```

in that when a user selects a row with a radio button I want all the data on that  row.
so, we do :

```
var theSelectedRadioButton = theForm.find('input[name="sample"]:checked');
```

how can I get all the  corresponding values in td's.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) on the radio button to find the `tr` it's in, and then [`children`](http://api.jquery.com/children) to find all of the `td`s in that row:

```
var tds = theSelectedRadioButton.closest('tr').children('td');
```

Then extract the information from the `td`s, possibly in a loop using [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each) or [`map`](http://api.jquery.com/map). You haven't said where the information is, but for instance if you wanted their HTML:

```
var tdhtml = theSelectedRadioButton.closest('tr').children('td').map(function(td) {
    return $(this).html();
}).get();
```

...results in an array of strings in `tdhtml` containing the HTML of each `td`. (Note the easily-missed call to [`get`](http://api.jquery.com/get) at the end: `map` returns a jQuery object even though the contents of it aren't DOM elements, `get` converts it into a normal array.)

Alternately if the information is stored in `data-*` attributes on the `td`s (`data-foo` in this example):

```
var tddata = theSelectedRadioButton.closest('tr').children('td').map(function(td) {
    return $(this).attr('data-foo');
}).get();
```

Comment: thank you I have updated with the form data also. when I keep a alert I am getting :tds  as object object ..is there way easier than this

Comment: @TheLearner: Right, `tds` is an object. It's a jQuery wrapper for the set of matched `td` elements. I showed you how to extract information from those elements (as arrays). Strongly recommend not using `alert` for this stuff. All major browsers have at least a half-decent debugger built in: http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/03/no-excuse.html Use a proper tool and you can inspect the contents `tds` / `tdhtml` / `tddata` and even (with several of those) use interactive code to figure out how to process it.

Answer (score 1):

```
var theSelectedRow = theSelectedRadioButton.closest('tr');
```

should give you the row, from there you can access the data in the row.

Aside: You can bind the data processing function to the radio button, then you don't need to "find" it.

Answer (score 1):

[***jsFiddle Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/BWaBu/)

When the value of the target input field changes, you can find use [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) to find the appropriate row, and then collect the values of each of the children into a new object.

```
$(theForm).find('input[name="sample"]').change(function() {

    var vals = $(this).closest('tr').children('td').map( function() {
        return $(this).find('input').val();
    }).toArray();
});
```